# Check whether the given number is fasinating or not

Tags: java

I am doing question on geeksforgeeks and i have come up with a question.

Given a number N. Your task is to check whether it is fascinating or not.
Fascinating Number: When a number(should contain 3 digits or more) is multiplied by 2 and 3 ,and when both these products are concatenated with the original number, then it results in all digits from 1 to 9 present exactly once.

Example 1:

Input:
N = 192
Output: Fascinating
Explanation: After multiplication with 2
and 3, and concatenating with original
number, number will become 192384576
which contains all digits from 1 to 9.

Example 2:

Input:
N = 853
Output: Not Fascinating
Explanation: It's not a fascinating
number.

Your Task:
You don't need to read input or print anything. Your task is to complete the function fascinating() which takes the integer n parameters and returns boolean denoting the answer.

Expected Time Complexity: O(1)
Expected Auxiliary Space: O(1)

Constraints:
100 <= N <= 107

i have to complete the following fascinating function my code is returning error.

```
class Solution {
boolean fascinating(String q) {
    // code here
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<q.length(); i++){
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(q.charAt(i)));
    }
    if(sum == 45){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

When i saw the solution code i am not able to understand how it is doing the things.

```
class Solution {
boolean fascinating(String q) {
    int A[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 0}; // to store count of every digit from '0' to '9'
    int i, flag = 0;
    char ch;
    for (i = 0; i < q.length(); i++) {
        ch = q.charAt(i);
        A[ch - 48]++;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        // checking if every digit from '1' to '9' are present exactly once
        // or not
        if (A[i] != 1) {
            flag = 1; // flag is set to 1 if frequency is not 1
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
}
```

Can anyone please explain this to me it will be very helpful.

Comment: *"Your task is to complete the function fascinating() which takes the **integer n** parameters"* Which would be a `fascinating(int n)` method, but your method is `fascinating(String q)`, so how is that supposed to be a solution?

Comment: Could you explain, what exactly don't you understand?

Comment: @ColeHenrich No, GeeksforGeeks didn't write that. It would of course be nice to have a link to GFG, so here it is: [Fascinating Number - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fascinating-number/). Now we can see that GFG actually wrote `boolean isFascinating(int num)`

Comment: @ColeHenrich Seems you need a refresher in how Unicode/ASCII characters work. As a character, the digit `'0'` is numeric ASCII value 48, so subtracting 48 is correct, though it would be better written as `ch - '0'`, documenting the fact that 48 is the digit 0. --- *FYI:* `Integer.parseInt(q.charAt(i))` doesn't even compile, so you're definitely wrong about that.

Comment: @Andreas interesting! That changes a lot of the above comments!

Comment: (delete), (delete), (delete) :)!

Comment: @Andreas that was actually VERY helpful. Now it makes total sense. Maybe not worthy of answering considering the earlier blunders, but here goes!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
```

`fascinating` returns a boolean, true/false to the question, "is it fascinating?"

```
boolean fascinating(String q) {

int A[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
           0, 0, 0, 0}; // to store count of every digit from '0' to '9'
```

Here you just initialize A as an array of zeroes, effectively (but not technically) 'empty'.

```
int i, flag = 0; 
    char ch;
```

Here you initialize `i` and `flag` at 0 and declare `ch`.

```
for (i = 0; i < q.length(); i++) {
        ch = q.charAt(i);
        A[ch - 48]++;
    }
```

Here you have a `for` loop that goes through each character in `q`.

For example, let q = 192384576. This is not N, but rather N concatenated with (Nx2) concatenated with (Nx3).

So the `for` loop first sets `ch = q.charAt(0)`. This is the first character, 1. Then it increments (adds one to) a certain index in `A`.

This index, much credit and thanks to Andreas for explaining this, is the difference of the Numeric ASCII value for `ch` and 48, which is the Numeric ASCII value for 0.

In Numeric ASCII:

```
0 = 48
1 = 49
2 = 50 
3 = 51

and the rest.
```

Therefore, `ch-48` will give the index in `A` that should represent `ch`. For example, when `ch` is 1, ASCII value of `ch` is `49` and `49-48 = 1`. Therefore, it goes to `A[1]` and increments it.

Remember, arrays go `[0,1,2,3, etc.]` So it goes to `[0, 0, 0, etc]` and adds one to the *second* 0 -- `A[1]`, thus making `A = [0,1,0,etc]`.

It continues through each digit in `q`, and thus fills the array `A`.

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        // checking if every digit from '1' to '9' are present exactly once
        // or not
        if (A[i] != 1) {
            flag = 1; // flag is set to 1 if frequency is not 1
            break;
        }
    }
```

Here, it iterates through `A`, set to length `10` because we are checking 0-9, and checks at each index if the value in that index is equal to 1. Hence,
if (A[i]!=1){}

The array should look like `[1,1,1,1,etc].`
If *any* of these indices is found not to be 1, it sets `flag = 1` and immediately will `break` or *exit* the `for` loop.

```
if (flag == 1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
}
```

This final `if-else` statement checks whether `flag` is equal to `1`. Remember, we only set it equal to 1 if the array is not uniformly filled with 1's, meaning the String `q` does not contain exactly one of each digit 0-9.

If `flag` is 1, `return false`, meaning it is not fascinating. Otherwise, it is fascinating. Thus, when fascinating, `return true`.